# How to change specific property in an element of an Observable Collection on PropertyChange?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` with more `columns` and `rows`. What I'd like is to make that if I `change a ComboBox in row 1, the Combo in row 2 should chage with it`, but nothing else. I use an `Observable Collection` which stores the `classes`. I have no idea how to make it...

The `Collection`:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> ceilingItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = language.GetString("top-mesh"), Name = "4. " + language.GetString("main-direction"), Value1 = list1, Unit1 = "mm", Value2 = list2, Unit2 = "cm", IsEditable = true });
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = "", Name = "3. " + language.GetString("side-direction"), Value1 = list1, Unit1 = "mm", Value2 = list2, Unit2 = "cm", IsEditable = false });
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = language.GetString("bottom-mesh"), Name = "2. " + language.GetString("side-direction"), Value1 = list1, Unit1="mm", Value2 = list2, Unit2 = "cm", IsEditable = false });
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = "", Name = "1. " + language.GetString("main-direction"), Value1 = list1, Unit1 = "mm", Value2 = list2, Unit2 = "cm", IsEditable = true });
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = language.GetString("lace"), Name = "", Value1 = list1, Unit1 = "mm", Value2 = list2, Unit2 = "cm", IsEditable = true });
ceilingItems.Add(new Item() { Category = language.GetString("spacer-iron"), Name = "", Value1 = list1, Unit1="mm", Value2 = list3, Unit2 = language.GetString("piece") + " / m2", IsEditable = true });
```

For example: if I change `Value1` in the `first element`, `Value1` has to be the same in the `second element`, but just there. (This is because of the function for what we will use them...) This collection is binded to `DataGrid Columns`.

The `Item` class:

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Unit1 { get; set; }
    public List<double> Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Unit2 { get; set; }
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It is totally unclear how any possible ComboBox uses your Item class. Besides that, the INotifyPropertyChanged is obviously incomplete. Any property that should notify a Binding, must fire the PropertyChanged event from its setter (as you were already told before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to play with `SelectedValue` of your Comboboxes in `row 1` and `2`.

Supposing both Comboboxes are `Binded` to the same collection so you can guarantee that the possible values of both are always the same, then you have to sync `ComboBoxes` `SelectedValue` property: once the `SelectedValue` changes on `ComboBox` at row 1 you need to set the `SelectedValue` of `ComboBox` at row 2 to the same value.

Some hints to do it.

**Way 1**

Let the `Grid` `ViewModel` synch the `SelectedValue` supposing it contains an `ObservableCollection<ViewModelRow>`.
This way is some boring cause you need to implement a mechanism to monitor the synch the `SelectedValue` changes of any synch the `ViewModelRow` in your collection.

**Way 2**

This solution get you better code maintenance and also let you code less than the first solution.

You need to use Message Broker design pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker you can implement your own Message Broker or simply use one of any MVVM Toolkit libraries that already implement it. Most of the existing MVVM Toolkits have their own Message Broker implementation. So no need to re-invent the whell.

For example, the MVVM Light Toolkit Message Broker is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/mvvm-the-mvvm-light-messenger-in-depth#using-messages

So you can let the broker send a `Message` when `SelectedValue` of `ComboBox` at first row changes then the `ViewModel` Binded to `ComboBox` at second row can subscribe to this message and react selecting its own `SelectedValue` property accordingly.

**Warning**

Does the behavior you described be the same in case the `SelectedValue` of `Combobox` at row 2 changes?
If yes then be carefull to avoiding loops that must be handled.

I hope this help.