# MVVM WPF: Remove element from DataGridComboBoxColumn based on selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Currently i have a datagrid that contains some columns. One of these columns is a DataGridComboBoxColumn.
This is bound to a two classes. SelectedValueBinding is bound to my Model class property called HMDGroup. The item source is bound to a list from my ViewModel called HMDGroups;

I am looking for a way to remove an item from the list in the combobox, based on if the same item is already selected in another comboxbox in the same column.

For example I already have selected 136b6407 and 136b6408 for two cells, it shouldn't be possible to select them again in the next cell, unless it is removed from the other cells.

[Image showing example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwNov.png)

I am quite new to the MVVM pattern and not sure how to solve this the MVVM way, since it is bound to a list.

Many thanks for your help!

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="VariantHandlerDatagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" ItemsSource="{Binding variantHandlerItems}" SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="False" GridLinesVisibility="None"
              HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserSortColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" ColumnWidth="*" >
       <DataGrid.Resources>
            <local:VHViewModel x:Key="ComboItems"/>
       </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Variant Name" Binding="{Binding Variant}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="hmdComboCol" Header="HMD Group" 
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding HMDGroup, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HMDGroups, Source={StaticResource ComboItems}}"/> 
         </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```
 sealed class VHViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   
    private List<string> usedHMDGroups = new List<string>();
    private List<string> startHMDGroups = new List<string>{
                "136b6405",
                "136b6406",
                "136b6407",
                "136b6408",
                "136b6409",
                "136b6410",
                "None"
            };

    public List<string> HMDGroups
    {
        get 
        {
            return startHMDGroups;
            
        }
        set 
        {
            startHMDGroups = value;
            OnPropertyChange("HMDGroups");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
sealed class VariantMapping : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string hmdGroup;

    public string HMDGroup
    {
        get { return hmdGroup; }
        set
        {
            hmdGroup = value;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hmdGroup))
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(smdGroup))
                {
                    variant = "None";
                    OnPropertyChange("Variant");
                    OnPropertyChange("HMDGroup");
                }
                else
                {
                    variant = smdGroup;
                    OnPropertyChange("Variant");
                    OnPropertyChange("HMDGroup");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                variant = hmdGroup;
                OnPropertyChange("Variant");
                OnPropertyChange("HMDGroup");
            }
        }
    }

   
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: you're breaking MVVM by binding view to model. view is not supposed to know about existence of model.

Comment: @Bizhan how else should i bind the columns to get the correct value in the cells?

Comment: The key here is to add logic to the setter your `HDMGroup` property to remove the item from your `HMDGroups` collection when it gets called. Your `HMDGroups` collection will also have to be an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List` since list doesn't notify the UI when items are removed or added.

Comment: by adhering to the MVVM principles. `V <-> VM -> M`. usually you need to implement one VM per each part of the View. and in each VM provide logic to read or write Models. sometimes it's best to keep the reference of Model in the VM for convenience. but you need to be cautious about the state of the Model to make sure it's not outdated

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with `SelectedValue` of `ComboBox` with value `136b6407` and the list binded to the other `ComboBox`.

Some hints to do it.

**Way 1**

Let the main Grid ViewModel synch the SelectedValue of `ComboBox` with value `136b6407` to the other `ComboBox` by removing the selected item frmo the binded list. This way is some boring cause you need to implement a mechanism to synch the 2 ViewModel binded to the `ComboBoxes` manually

**Way 2**

This solution get you better code maintenance and also let you code less than the first solution.

You need to use Message Broker design pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker you can implement your own Message Broker or simply use one of any MVVM Toolkit libraries that already implement it. Most of the existing MVVM Toolkits have their own Message Broker implementation. So no need to re-invent the whell.

For example, the MVVM Light Toolkit Message Broker is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/mvvm-the-mvvm-light-messenger-in-depth#using-messages

So you can let the broker send a Message when SelectedValue of ComboBox with value `136b6407` ViewModel Binded to other ComboBox can subscribe to this message and react removing the item from its own binded list.

To get further info have a look at this answer on SO that refers to this solution: [How to change specific property in an element of an Observable Collection on PropertyChange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62553871/how-to-change-specific-property-in-an-element-of-an-observable-collection-on-pro/62554169#62554169)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will look into it and get back.

Comment: You are telling me to play with value of combobox and the list binded to the other combobox. The same list is bound to all comboboxes. So if I remove the selectedvalue string from the list, it will just make the combobox blank. What is the fix here?

Comment: @BenjaminMadsen: you may call `<your_observablecollection>.ToList()` to clone it when needed